# Is there a known worst start configuration for Ford-Johnson sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, sorting

By this I mean a permutation of the $n$ input items to be sorted such that the number of comparisons taken to produce the correct order is maximal over all of the possible permutations of $n$ items.

Is there a pattern like all input ascending is worst case, or even some class of input permutations that have been proved to lead to worse performance than others?

Comment: I deleted your example because I didn't think it was helpful to have a completely made-up example that didn't even really show what it was supposed to show (giving the number of comparisons needed for three particular permutations doesn't demonstrate that one of those is the worst case). I think the concept's clear enough without an example.

Comment: 1. Can you give a self-contained specification of the Ford-Johnson algorithm or a reference to where it is specified?  2. Have you tried implementing it and running it exhaustively on all possible inputs of length $n$ (for some small values of $n$, say $n \le 8$) to see what the worst-case inputs are and see if you can spot any patterns?

Comment: That's my next step, but I just wanted to check if there are any existing results before I devote time to researching this topic. The only free (partial) reference to it that I've found is http://www.xomnom.com/fja.html.